# how to pass text file as argument in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

```
the text file contains 

from:sender@gmail.com
to:receiver@gmail.com
subject:
attachment:asdfg.xlsx
```

all arguments should be handled in shell script
I tried but if subject contains space then it gives problem

```
    from=$(echo $1|cut -d ":" -f 2 <<< "$1")
    to=$(echo $2|cut -d ":" -f 2 <<< "$2")
    subject="$3"
    attachment=$(echo $4|cut -d ":" -f 2 <<< "$4")
```

Comment: The assignment to `subject` just stores all of the content of `$3` into the variable `subject`, including the spaces, and you do not show how you are populating your positional parameters. Further, "gives problem" is hardly an adequate description of a problem. I suggest that you write a new question, showing your program, the input, the output you get, and the output you expect.

Answer (score 2):

When you could read the Input_file then passing it as a variable will not be a good option IMHO, so create variables inside script by reading Input_file, opting OP's method of creating variables but enhancing code to `awk`.

```
from=$(awk -F':' '/from/{print $NF}' Input_file)
to=$(awk -F':' '/^to/{print $NF}' Input_file)
subject=$(awk -F':' '/^subject/{if($NF){print $NF} else {print "NULL subject"}}' Input_file)
attachment=$(awk -F':' '/^attachment/{print $NF}' Input_file)
```

Comment: i want to create a universal script were text file will keep on changing and that would be pass as argument

Comment: @itsvinit, I didn't get it, this code will take care of sequence of lines, so even then its useful, if this is not you meant then please do mention more details on your previous comments please and lemme know.

Comment: how to handel spaces of subject when its pass as an argument?

Comment: @itsvinit, Trust me if you pass file like this it will more helpful and easy to maintain your script. Also most importantly this is taking care of that space thing too, lemme know if you test it.